# HTML & CSS: display two block side by side with 2 button

Tags: html, css, frontend

I' m trying some simple exercise to improve my web development skills. I' m doing a simple translator. Of course for the front end I'm using HTML and CSS. For the backend I'm using Java Servlet.

I want to show two textarea one next to the other and two button under the text area on the left for translating and swapping the language(kind of google translate but with two buttons on the left of the first text area).

I achieved in a tricky way(I suppose?) what I want. But I think there is a better way to do it. Here is the fiddle. Someone can give me an hint, or any explanation on how do it or how works for align elements? Thank you!
Code here:

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>Translator</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>Welcome to translator!</h1>

  <div class="div1">
    <form id="form1">
        <textarea class="inline-textarea" id="text1" form="form1"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Translate" id="translate">
        <input type="submit" value="Swap" id="swap">
    </form>
</div>

<div class="div2">
    <form id="form2">
        <textarea class="inline-textarea" id="text2" form="form2"></textarea>
    </form>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jsScript.js"></script>
  </body>
 </html>
```

`style.css`

```
body {
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.div1 {
 float: left;
 margin-right: 2px;
}

#translate {
 display: block;
}

#swap {
 float: right;
 position: relative;
 margin-top: -21.2px;
 margin-right: 35px;    
}
```

Here the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/8e6s1d25/

Comment: What you have done is right. That's totally fine. `:)`

Comment: But the swap button isn't perfectly aligned with the translate button, there is a better way than specifying the margin of the swap button for achieving the result? Thank you!

Comment: Okay, I can see that you have done something totally crazy. Can you wait for a few moments I can give you a best solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I am not sure if you need two forms. You are just better off with one single form. And I am going to use two columns inside the `<form>` so that there's the input on the left and output on the right, as how you see in the Google Translate.

Next thing is that, I am not sure why you needed to give the <kbd>Translate</kbd> button, a `display: block`, which is causing you the problem. Combining all the above said, I have made a simple snippet below, that looks like the preview below:

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5em;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0;
}
.input, .output {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Welcome to translator!</h1>
<form action="">
  <div class="input">
    <textarea name="input" id="input"></textarea>
    <input type="button" value="Translate" />
    <input type="button" value="Swap" />
  </div>
  <div class="output">
    <textarea name="output" id="output"></textarea>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

Hope this is helpful. Feel free to ask any question to make yourself clear on the coding standards. What I have used is the one that's being used in live production sites. `:)`

Comment: Amazing, thank you! I need to really understand your css cause it looks so cool!

Comment: @SpaghettiFunk Definitely... Tell me what you don't understand. Happy to explain you. `:D`

Comment: The solution is working in FireFox but not in Google Chrome. It looks like that in google chrome there are trouble with the -webkit property. Do you have an explanation? Thank you!

Comment: @SpaghettiFunk I took the screenshot from the latest version of Google Chrome. What version do you use?

Comment: @SpaghettiFunk Mine's `Version 67.0.3396.87 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

Comment: @SpaghettiFunk Show me a screenshot on how it looks. You can use imgur.com to host the image and send the link to me.

Comment: I have the same Chrome version. Now the css is applied but there is no trace of js script. If I go in : Inspector->Source->js->jsScript.js the text of the script is empty, there is no code. Chrome sounds little bit bugged. It could be a WAMP problem? Because with FireFox Everything is fine!

Comment: @SpaghettiFunk Tell me one thing. Can you run the code snippet in my answer using Chrome and you still have issues, let me know, then it's a code issue. Else, the issue is elsewhere and needs debugging. Your answer now is important...

Comment: I can run your snippet in Chrome without error. Now is working also in Chrome both the css and the js. It could be a cache problem?